# Importing ethers via Hardhat fails despite official testing documentation

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

According to the [official testing documentation](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts.html) for Hardhat, `ethers` should be available implicitly within the global scope; however, it can optionally be `require`d explicitly, like so:

```js
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
```

This fails for my local project.

My package manifest seems to include the correct dependencies:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.1",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.1",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts#v4.0.0-beta.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.1",
    "hardhat": "^2.0.11"
  }
}
```

My unit tests file seems to match the worked example in the Hardhat documentation also:

```js
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("Distributor.sol", function() {
    it("Distribution should fail for non-owners", async function() {
        const DistributorFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Distributor");
        const Distributor = await Distributor.deploy();

        Distributor.distribute([], []);

        expect(await hardhatToken.totalSupply()).to.be.revertedWith("foobar");
    });
});
```

Despite this, running the tests fails with:

```sh
$ yarn hardhat test
yarn run v1.22.5
$ /home/bob/dev/misc/token-distributor/node_modules/.bin/hardhat test


  Distributor.sol
undefined
    1) Distribution should fail for non-owners


  0 passing (9ms)
  1 failing

  1) Distributor.sol
       Distribution should fail for non-owners:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContractFactory' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/Distributor.js:8:49)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)



error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the require in your `hardhat.config.js`

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
```

And remove this line from your test file:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
```

Then, you can use `ethers` in your tests. Hardhat looks in the config first before running tests. If you have required a package that includes `ethers` you can use it in the global scope.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1. you need to install `ethers` separately too, as given in the [instructions for `hardhat-ethers`](https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers.html), e.g.
   `npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers 'ethers@^5.0.0'`
2. Every Hardhat plugin needs to be registered in the Hardhat config file (`hardhat.config.js`):
   `require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");`

There is no need to remove the explicit import in your test file, however, Hardhat docs recommend following this style:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");
const { ethers } = hre;
```

Answer (score 0):

It still shows error, `reading ethers undefined`, I started the project all again with `yarn hardhat` and chose the first option "Create Simple Project" and it works perfectly.